# Timeout Waiting for Visible iframe

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm learning Selenium with Python, and attempting to write happy path flow for a website.  Where I get stuck is a part of the flow where an iframe is automatically launched after clicking through a pop-up window.  I've tried several different methods, but am unable to locate the frame, or wait for it appear.  Either it's not found or times out.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'continue-  reservation'))).click()


# cvv2 form
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'cvv_iframe')))
```

Error:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'cvv_iframe')))
File "/Users/anutter/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

HTML is as follows:

```
                <div id="cpstaging" class="emptystage">
                    <div class="fixed h-v-centered new-preload" style="display: none;"><span class="fa fa-spinner f-50 f-grn fa-pulse"></span></div>
                </div>
                <div id="cvv-box" class="pad-30-lr">
                    <div id="enter-cvv-title" class="blk mar-20-b f-18 border-b pad-10-b">Enter CVV Code</div>
                    <iframe src="https://qa-hotels.ecbsn.com/cvv?oauth_token=u7q99%2Fe8I%2BkUrkLMr4dGR2t4gmcDbVtr&amp;type=visa&amp;src=web-desktop" id="cvv_iframe" name="cvv_iframe" width="430" height="160" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, added html as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to access the elements within the `<iframe>` you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* using either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `ID`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"cvv_iframe")))
    ```
  - Using `NAME`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"cvv_iframe")))
    ```
  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#cvv_iframe[name='cvv_iframe']")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='cvv_iframe' and @name='cvv_iframe']")))
    ```
- Note: As per your code trials the **ID** of the `<iframe>` isn't `cvv-iframe` but **`cvv_iframe`**

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: D'oh, that was super obvious.  Unfortunately, after correcting the iframe name I'm still getting a timeout exception.  Maybe I'm not using the correct ID?  I've tried several others ID's, as well as using CSS selector, and nothing has been successful.

Comment: @anutter Your comment doesn't help me either. Sorry, the answer didn't help you to solve your problem but how am I going to improve my post with that feedback?

Comment: I updated the description with the error, as well as the more of the HTML for the page, not sure what else I can add to make my issue clearer?